# Dropbox on Android, onResume() fail

Tags: android, dropbox

I tried to implement dropbox on android, but even "example" from [dropbox page](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android) won't work. In code below i changed only my Key (to "MY_KEY"). It shows this error during "log in" process because `session.authenticationSuccessful()` is false. and thats because `mApi.getSession().startAuthentication(DBRoulette.this)` and/or `mApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(DBRoulette.this)` propably failed. But in my opinion everything should be ok - i have correct my Key and Secret, permisions and key in manifest and also configuration of libraries should be fine. I also tried implement [this example](http://javatechig.com/android/share-file-to-dropbox-in-android-example) but still with the same error. I can post more info if needed, but basically i didn't changed code at all - only tried to change some methods that i found, but without success.

Error during "log in" proces.

```
   12-02 16:11:34.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1501): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.dropbox.android.sample/com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://www.dropbox.com:443/1/connect?locale=en_US&k=MY_KEY&s=&state=oauth2:d953b22cfa534a73ba088fc6fd03e47a }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't know Dropbox on phone needs internet browser (even when someone use all keys, secret, persmissions and so) - In video tutorials i watched they simply skip this part because of private information. I also didn't know, that even when i used AVD from latest API it won't have internet browser. And no internet browser is mentioned in examples and it was only thing missing.
So changing AVD fixed problem.